# How to find top-X highest values in column using Django Queryset without cutting off ties at the bottom?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have the following Django Model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    score = models.FloatField()
```

There are thousands of values in the DB for this model. I would like to efficiently and elegantly use that QuerySets alone to get the top-ten highest scores and display the names with their scores in descending order of score. So far it is relatively easy.

Here is where the wrinkle is: If there are multiple myModels who are tied for tenth place, I want to show them all. I don't want to only see some of them. That would unduly give some names an arbitrary advantage over others. If absolutely necessary, I can do some post-DB list processing outside of Querysets. However, the main problem I see is that there is no way I can know apriori to limit my DB query to the top 10 elements since for all I know there may be a million records all tied for tenth place.

Do I need to get all the myModels sorted by score and then do one pass over them to calculate the score-threshold? And then use that calculated score-threshold as a filter in another Queryset?

If I wanted to write this in straight-SQL could I even do it in a single query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course you can do it in one SQL query. Generating this query using django ORM is also easily achievable.

```
top_scores = (myModel.objects
                     .order_by('-score')
                     .values_list('score', flat=True)
                     .distinct())
top_records = (myModel.objects
                      .order_by('-score')
                      .filter(score__in=top_scores[:10]))
```

This should generate single SQL query (with subquery).

Comment: Not only is this a good answer, but I also love the use of braces to avoid using `\\` at the end of lines.

Comment: This will get all objects with a score that match any of the top 10 _scores_, **not** the top 10 elements + any extras (because of `.distinct()`). So if you have 10 elements with a score of 100, 10 with 99 etc, you will end up with 100 results instead of the desired 10. Michal's answer doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @dwurf I think the question was exactly how to get 100 results in the example you've provided. BTW Michal's answer behaves the same way as mine.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz nonsense. Saqib explicitly states that he wants to include all elements that tie _for last place_. Michal's code will do this. Your code will include all elements that tie for any of the ten highest scores (yes, I've tested it). Simply remove the `.distinct()` and your code behaves correctly, although you might want to add Michal's excellent advice about index creation.

Comment: @dwurf if my understanding of Saqib question is correct, he wants all ties in top positions.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can also do it with two SQL queries, what might be faster with some databases than the single SQL query approach (IN operation is usually more expensive than comparing):

```
myModel.objects.filter(
    score__gte=myModel.objects.order_by('-score')[9].score
)
```

Also while doing this, you should really have an index on score field (especially when talking about millions of records):

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    score = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
```

Comment: Won't this simply choose the 9th element of `myModel.objects.order_by('-score')`? You probably meant to do `myModel.objects.order_by('-score')[:9]`

Comment: It chooses 9th score and then filters all models with higher score. Your approach should work as well...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @KrzysztofSzularz's answer, you can use raw sql to do this too.

There are 2 SQL operations to get what you want

```
SELECT score from my_application_mymodel order by score desc limit 10;
```

Above sql will return top 10 scores (`limit` does this)

```
SELECT name, score from my_application_mymodel where score in (***) order by score desc;
```

That will return you all the results whom score value is within the first query result.

```
SELECT name, score from my_application_mymodel where score in (SELECT score from my_application_mymodel order by score desc limit 10) order by score desc;
```

You can use [Raw Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries), but probably you will got error messages while you try to run this. So [using custom queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) is the best

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name, score from my_application_mymodel where score in (SELECT score from my_application_mymodel order by score desc limit 10) order by score desc;")
return cursor.fetchall()
```

That will return you a list:

```
[("somename", 100.9),
 ("someothername", 99.9)
...
]
```

Django names tables according to your django model name (all lowercase) and application name in which your model lives under and join these to with an underscore. Like `my_application_mymodel`